# Design for Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns

first post here so be nice! I will try to be the most precise and concise possible.

I'm currently developing a GUI in Angular/Typescript which displays the devices and network traffic of the LAN and nearby. I'm having a bit of trouble with the design of my application so far.

I have several device classes:

**Device**

```
export class Device {
  _id: string
  _mac: string
  ...
}
```

**LANDevice**

```
export class LANDevice extends Device {
  _firstSeen: Date
  _status: 'reachable' | 'unreachable'
  _services: Service[]
  ...
}
```

I have other classes to describe other type of devices like Bluetooth, BLE devices etc.
I would like to have several components (Summary, Services & vulnerabilities and Activity) that displays some information about those devices.

The problem I'm facing is that, depending on the device type, the information to display will be very different.

How do I design my components and classes to handle this use case ? 
Should I have a functon in each device class to expose the 'right' model to the concerned component (but I would need to write a function for each component so not a good idea I believe)

**Device**

```
export class Device {
  ...
  public toSummary(): SummaryModel {
    icon: this._svgIcon(),
    name: this._hostname,
    content: [
      firstSeen: this._firstSeen,
      network: [ ... ]
    ] 
  }

}
```

**BluetoothDevice**

```
export class Device {
  ...
  public toSummary(): SummaryModel {
    icon: this._svgIcon(),
    name: this._hostname,
    content: [
      lastSeen: this._lastSeen,
      macVendor: this._macVendor
    ] 

  }

}
```

And in my Summary component have:

**SummaryComponent**

```
export interface SummaryModel {
  icon: <Base64>,
  name: string,
  content: []
}


export class SummaryComponent {
  ...

  **Parsing of device.toSummary() function with keys/values with table-like display**
  **Key1: Value1
  **Key2: Value2
  **...

}
```

Does anyone have better ideas ? 
The main problem here is that, depending on the device type, I don't want to display the same things. I could chech the device type and handle this in the component or HTML but I believe that a Component in Angular should have a single interface/data model and handle only this.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would design this by using [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) and [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

You can make your component display whichever case of the switch depending on the result of some expression that does logic to determine what underlying type the entity is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's what I'm doing at the moment, I guess I will stick with it then :)